# Как удалить файл на заданное количество байт?

Tags: java

Добрый день, отправляю файл и хочу реализовать удаление его ровно на то количество байт сколько уже было отправлено (понятно что байты должны удалятся с начала файла) и так при каждом подключение к сети. Остановился на том, что получаю число байт на которое его нужно удалить, но что дальше с этим числом делать не знаю ?

Как  удалить файл на заданное количество байт?

```
    int countFiles = list.size();//создаём переменную countFiles (подсчёт файлов)

    DataOutputStream outD; // переменная потока отправляемых данных

    try {

        outD = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        outD.writeInt(countFiles);//отсылаем количество файлов

        for (int i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
            File f = new File(list.get(i));

            outD.writeLong(f.length());//отсылаем размер файла
            outD.writeUTF(f.getName());//отсылаем имя файла

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
            int count;//колличество отправленых байт

            while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outD.write(buffer, 0, count);
                delFile(count,f); //  вызываем метод удаления из отправляемого файла переданых байт
            }
            outD.flush();
            in.close();
        }
        client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void delFile(int count, File f) {//метод удаление байт из файла 

    count1 = count;//колличество отправленых байт

    File folder = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Photo_and_Video");// доступ к папке с файлами
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();// получаем список файлов
    for (File f1 : listOfFiles) {

        if(f1.getName().equals(f.getName())){// сравниваем имена файлов отправленного и оставшегося

            delReadByte =  count1 - f1.length();//получаем количество байт которое надо удалить из файла


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Удалить фрагмент нельзя с обычными файлами ни в одном языке.

Поэтому просто открываете новый файл, копируете туда начало (до точки удаления или вставки), потом либо пропускаете фрагмент, либо наоборот дописываете. Далее старый файл стираете и новый переименовываете. Это всё стандартными средствами делается.